# How to present multiple table views in a Master-Detail application?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to use the "Master-Detail" template in my app. This template comes with a single `UITableView` only. How would I go about adding an extra `UITableView`? The user browses through the 1st table view, then the 2nd and eventually arrives at the `Detail View Controller`.

[image]

I placed a new `UITableView` and set up a few Segues. This is what my Storyboard looks like:

[image]

When tapped, `UITableViewCells` get highlighted. Though, there is no way I can access the 2nd `UITableView`.

What am I doing wrong? How to implement multiple table views in a Master-Detail application?

Comment: When you created the segue, did you Ctrl-drag from the prototype cell in the first tableView?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, thanks for pointing that out! I should have mentioned it in my question.

Comment: If the segue is connected from the prototype cell, you do not need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (I suspect this is causing the crash).  The segue should be triggered automatically when you select the cell.  Also, you don't need to use a second navigation controller, since your first table view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller.  You can use a show segue linked directly from the cell to the second table view controller.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks! This is very helpful. I just deleted the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and the navigation controller in the Storyboard (it looks like this now http://i.imgur.com/V2Tan7Z.png). Which segues do I need to create? The table view is now missing a navigation controller, so I guess I need to do something here? Thanks!

Comment: Add a Show segue by dragging from the prototype cell in the first TV controller to the second TV controller

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks! I got it working! Feel free to post your last comment as an answer. I'll be glad to accept it, as it solved my problem :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments....

If the segue is connected from the prototype cell, you do not need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (I suspect this is causing the crash). The segue should be triggered automatically when you select the cell.

Also, you don't need to use a second navigation controller, since your first table view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller. You can use a `show` segue linked directly from the cell to the second table view controller.

Add the `Show` segue by dragging from the prototype cell in the first TV controller to the second TV controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create multiple Segue for each UIViewController (Master and detail) in order to change their content. Pass data through prepareForSegue.
You can also simply update your tableView data and reload it within the same viewController. (I'm not a huge fan of this approach though, less "standard"; for example, if you want to add animation, it's easier with Segue in my opinion.)